# Permutation of cycles as transposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Every permutation of a finite set can be written as a cycle or as a product of disjoint cycles
>
> Every permutation in $S_n \forall n \geq$ 2 can be written as a product of transposition.

Suppose we have $\alpha=(123)(111)$

As a product of transposition, do I ignore the 'repeating' elements?

So that we have $(12)(13)(11)\equiv (12)(13)$?

Comment: The notation $(1\ 1\ 1)$ does not define a permutation, so you don't need to bother with that.

Comment: $(123)$ is a permutation but (1,1,1) is??..nothing actually